# How to do feature engineering with scikit learn pipelines?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing, pandas

When doing preprocessing I've always used pandas to impute, encode, or scale my data. In other words, I've done all of the steps "manually".

However, this takes a long time, generates a lot of code, and makes the whole workflow much more complicated in my opinion.
An alternative is using a scikit-learn pipeline that allows chaining multiple (preprocessing) steps to make the process more efficient, write less code, and avoid data leakage.

However, I've run across a problem when using pipelines: 
Since most feature engineering cannot be done without preprocessing the data, e.g. because of missing values, I have to do feature engineering *after* preprocessing.

 Okay, no problem so far. Now, when I do the preprocessing with a scikit learn pipeline, it returns a NumPy array with the imputed and, for example, one-hot-encoded features. It's now impossible to understand (or at least much harder to understand) which features are which. Especially because we don't have the column labels after they've been one-hot-encoded. We also cannot simply display the dataframe and think about what features could be engineered.

Now my questions: 
The above being the case, what is the best way to integrate feature engineering with a scikit learn pipeline?

p.s. the same question applies to feature selection.

Answer (score 1):

Pipeline objects have a `step` field which contains operators applied in each step.  You can have a look at that object to understand the meanings of the resulted features.

That said, if you are doing feature engineering manually by looking at the data, then you will have to do it in mostly the same way as before: Do it step by step, look at the intermediate results and think about good ways to convert the data.  Pipeline would help you to compile the entire process into a single, compact object after the engineering process is done.

Alternatively, you may want to find helpful features in more automatic ways, such as grid search over hyperparameter spaces.  For that purpose, the pipeline will be a great help because you can optimize the entire pipeline as a whole, as opposed to optimizing each single step in the pipeline separately.